# How can I set data from position X to position Y inside child on particular group in ExpandListView?

Tags: android

**Problem:**

I have arraylist which contains all child items which is 5 child, now I have to divide into two group: General and other. For General (3) Ele bill, Insurance and landline  For Other(2): Gas and Water

[image: Latest screenshot please check]

**Here is my implementation:**

```
@Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        if (headerList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderName().equals(CommonUtils.GENERAL_HEADER)) {
            return CommonUtils.LANDLINE_ID;
        }

        if (headerList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderName().equals(CommonUtils.OTHER_HEADER)) {
            return CommonUtils.WATER_BILL_ID;
        }

        List<CustomCategory> countryList = headerList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryList();
        return countryList.size();
    }
```

Adapter:

```
package com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Interface.HamburgerMenuListener;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.CategoryHeader;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.CustomCategory;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.R;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableCategoryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = ExpandableCategoryAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private List<CategoryHeader> originalList;
    private List<CategoryHeader> headerList;
    private HamburgerMenuListener menuInterface;

    public ExpandableCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryHeader> generalList, HamburgerMenuListener menuInterface) {
        this.context = context;
        this.headerList = generalList;
        this.originalList = generalList;
        this.menuInterface = menuInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        List<CustomCategory> countryList = headerList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryList();
        return countryList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        CustomCategory customCategory = (CustomCategory) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_general_list, null);
        }

        TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_item);
        ImageView icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_category_icon);

        if (customCategory != null) {
            if (customCategory.getCustCategoryName() != null) {
                name.setText(customCategory.getCustCategoryName().trim());
            }

            if (customCategory.getIcon() != null) {
                icon.setImageResource(resources.getIdentifier(customCategory.getIcon(), "drawable",
                        context.getPackageName()));
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        if (headerList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderName().equals(CommonUtils.GENERAL_HEADER)) {
            return CommonUtils.LANDLINE_ID;
        }

        if (headerList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderName().equals(CommonUtils.OTHER_HEADER)) {
            return CommonUtils.WATER_BILL_ID;
        }

        List<CustomCategory> countryList = headerList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryList();
        return countryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return headerList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return headerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    private void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }


    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        CategoryHeader categoryHeader = (CategoryHeader) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_custom_category_list, null);
        }

        TextView heading = view.findViewById(R.id.header_view);
        heading.setText(categoryHeader.getHeaderName().trim());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void filterData(String query) {

        query = query.toLowerCase();
        headerList.clear();

        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            headerList.addAll(originalList);
        } else {

            for (CategoryHeader categoryHeader : originalList) {

                List<CustomCategory> countryList = categoryHeader.getCategoryList();
                List<CustomCategory> newList = new ArrayList<CustomCategory>();
                for (CustomCategory customCategory : countryList) {
                    if (customCategory.getCustCategoryName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                        newList.add(customCategory);
                    }
                }
                if (newList.size() > 0) {
                    CategoryHeader nContinent = new CategoryHeader(categoryHeader.getHeaderName(), newList);
                    headerList.add(nContinent);
                }
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Explained briefly:

See, I use SQLite DB, I have single table, from that table I get data and add into a new array list which size is 5. Now In my adapter's constructor, I got that array list. Now, in adapter I want to do some logic that will separate this list into two parent group according to my choice.

Comment: Sorry but I'm having a little trouble understanding your issue. Right now you have 10 items in each group, but you want to have 3 items in each group. Is this right? Can you explain a bit more about what the problem is.

Comment: @BilalNaeem Please see updated question. Actually 10 items was example, but in my case 1st group 3 items and 2nd group 5 items.

Comment: You want to group your items based on some parent type. Am I right?

Comment: @BilalNaeem Exactly. Like for genral I have to show 3 and for other I have to show 2, because total child items in my arraylist is 5.

Comment: Hi Arpi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that you don’t have to edit the question’s title to indicate that it is solved - this can be indicated by an accepted answer instead.

Comment: @Edric Ohh, but I've seen in some of questions similar to this tag. that's why I did and also it will appear on google search so user can check on google itself that whether is it solved or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is to keep some sort of flag/field in your child model which will indicate the group that these belong to. So, for example

```
class ChildModel {
    //This flag will indicate which group it belongs to
    int parentFlag;
}
```

When you are populating your adapter, you will need to check the flag to see which group the child belongs to and add it to that specific list.

**EDIT**

Let's say you get the list `originalList` in your adapter constructor. This list contains all the child objects that you got from your DB. In order to split them into groups you will need to make the following changes.

Change 1: You will need to split your data into a `HashMap` which will indicate the group type and child list. This is how you can achieve that

```
HashMap<Integer, List<CustomCategory>> groupChildMap = HashMap<>();
for (CustomCategory child: originalList) {
    int parentCategory = child.getParentCategory();

    if (groupChildMap.get(parentCategory) == null) {
            groupChildMap.put(parentCategory) = ArrayList<CustomCategory>();
    }
    List<CustomCategory> childList = groupChildMap.get(parentCategory);
    childList.add(child);
    groupChildMap.put(parentCategory, childList);
}
```

The above mentioned code block will convert your list of objects into groups based on the parent id. You will need to update your model slightly to store a flag which will indicate which group the object belongs to.

Change 2: After you have split your objects into the desired categories, you will need to fetch the objects and populate them into your list.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Here you first fetch the group and then fetch the child of that group
    int parentId = headerList.get(groupPosition).getId();
    CustomCategory childObject = groupChildMap.get(parentId).get(childPosition);
    //Here you have your object and can populate your view
}
```

The above code will fetch the exact child for each category and populate it.

Change 3: You will also need to update your item count method to handle this new change

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if (headerList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderName().equals(CommonUtils.GENERAL_HEADER)) {
        return CommonUtils.LANDLINE_ID;
    }

    if (headerList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderName().equals(CommonUtils.OTHER_HEADER)) {
        return CommonUtils.WATER_BILL_ID;
    }

    List<CustomCategory> childList = groupChildMap.get(headerList.get(groupPosition).getId());
    return childList.size();
}
```

Change 4: You will need to update your `CategoryHeader` model to contain an ID. Your child models `CustomCategory` will also have a new field `parentId` using which you can associate them with each other

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Let me know if this helps you out else I'll add some more code to make it a bit easier.

Comment: See, I use SQLite DB, I have single table, from that table I get data and add into a new array list which size is 5. Now In my adapter's constructor, I got that array list. Now, in adapter I want to do some logic that will separate this list into two parent group according to my choice.

Comment: No need to do this hashmap n all, I just added flag in my database  and in Category header, I add separate list according to header name.